# How to pass event from QML signal handler to base class

Tags: qt, qml

I have `TextField` object in which I want to slightly change behaviour of `onTabPressed`. I'm using `Keys` attached object for that:

```
Keys.onTabPressed: {
  model.item.value = text;
}
```

But then I lose its typical behaviour to switch between `TextField`s . In QtWidgets I would have done it with something like  `return QTextField::onTabPressed(event)`.

Are there any ways to achieve similar propagation of event to base class' event handler? In other words, is it possible to call base class' function from same function of derived class?

Answer (score 0):

Strange, I thought I've checked that. Solution is prevent an event from being accepted, then it propagates automatically, like shown in https://forum.qt.io/topic/19083/solved-work-around-qml-calling-overriden-functions/6 . In my case:

```
Keys.onTabPressed: {
  model.item.value = text;
  event.accepted = false
}
```